# How can i debug setText(String..) method of TextView?

Tags: android, android-listview

I am displaying arabic text, but vowel characters like "Shadda" are not getting positioned well. I am wondering if I could debug setText() method of TextView.. setText(..) is too complex how should i do it?

I don't want to make new class and override setText method. Is there any way through which I could use source code of TextView at -\Android_Sdk\sources\android-15\android\widget

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you are looking at the right place, but you can definitely watch android java source code inside eclipse while you debug, try setting it up with [these instructions](http://www.androidguys.com/2011/12/16/how-to-view-core-android-java-sources-in-eclipse/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20androidguyscom%20%28AndroidGuys%29).